# Slowly fade in the opacity of a particle system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write some code that **slowly** fades in the opacity of the particles when the player reaches at certain position.

The particle alpha value is changed when the player reaches the postion but it doesn't slowly fade, it just suddenly changes.

I am new to programming so I was wondering if I missing anything blatantly obvious. Thanks!

```
public class IncreaseFog : MonoBehaviour {

    Renderer rend;
    GameObject character; 
    float valToBeLerpedFrom = 9f;
    float tParam = 0f;
    float speed = 0.01f; 
    float characterPosition;
    Color c;    

    void Start () {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        character = GameObject.Find("CHARACTER");
    }

    void Update() {
        characterPosition = character.transform.position.x;
        if(characterPosition >= 190f) {
            StartCoroutine(increaseFog());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator increaseFog()
    {
        tParam = 0f;
        while (tParam < 1)
        {
            tParam +=  Time.deltaTime;  
            valToBeLerpedFrom = Mathf.Lerp(0f, 0.9f, tParam);
             c = rend.material.GetColor("_TintColor");
            c.a = (valToBeLerpedFrom);
            rend.material.SetColor("_TintColor", c);
        }
        rend.material.SetColor("_TintColor", c);
        yield return valToBeLerpedFrom;
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is that StartCoroutine  probably gets called multiple times because the player will remain past 190 as position. I think a better way would be to use a new GameObject in your scene, add BoxCollider component and then check `Trigger` on this component. Note that you'll need BoxCollider2D if your game is 2D or BoxCollider if your game is 3D. Add the following script to this trigger `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
// start fade fog.
    }` This will make sure that your code is only triggered once and it's more maintainable because you don't hardcode positions.

Comment: quite simply **do not call StartCoroutine(); from Update**.  Call it from Start.  enjoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have a while loop in it...you need to only execute it once each frame. As it stands now, your code won't complete until alpha is 0.9, so you never see the transition.

Comment: but how do i get it to fade over a certain amount of time without putting it in a loop?

Comment: @Night.owl Search the Unity docs for `coroutine`. Unity has a special feature added that allows your code to wait-for-next-frame-and-continue. This allows you to create one while loop, wait for a frame in the loop and continue (Using `yield return null` <- wait one frame).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using a box collider set as a trigger that calls the coroutine.

(thanks for the help)